# How to properly configure the Amazon EC2 AMI for 'hadoop-ec2'?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, ec2-api-tools

I am trying to launch an instance on Amazon EC2.  I have researched this problem extensively, but I have not found any helpful information.

When I run the command `hadoop-ec2 launch-cluster mycluster 2`, I receive the following error message:

```
Starting master with AMI.
Required parameter 'AMI' missing (-h for usage)
```

I have entered my AWS key, AWS secret key, AWS key pairs, etc.  I am using hadoop-1.0.4.  I am using the default S3 bucket (`hadoop-images`), but I have tried many other AMIs and I always get the same error message.

Has anybody experience this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is that the search for images the `launch-hadoop-master` script performs is not returning any results. The most likely cause of this due to the different AMIs that are available in different regions (but it could be due to any changes you've made to `S3_BUCKET` and `HADOOP_VERSION` in `hadoop-ec2-env.sh`).

From the `launch-hadoop-master` script:

```
# Finding Hadoop image
AMI_IMAGE=`ec2-describe-images -a | grep $S3_BUCKET 
                                  | grep $HADOOP_VERSION
                                  | grep $ARCH
                                  | grep available
                                  | awk '{print $2}'`

# Start a master
echo "Starting master with AMI $AMI_IMAGE"
```

So, it appears that `AMI_IMAGE` is not being set to a valid image and thus the search for AMIs that match the various `grep` filters is failing (the defaults for the Hadoop 1.0.4 distribution are `S3_BUCKET` is `hadoop-images`, `HADOOP_VERSION` is `0.19.0` and `ARCH` is `x86` if you're using m1.small instances). If you search the [public AMIs in the US-West-2 region](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-west-2#Images%3afilter=all-images;platform=all-platforms;visibility=public-images;search=hadoop), you'll see that there aren't many Hadoop images, but if you search the [public AMIs in the US-East-1 region](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Images%3afilter=all-images;platform=all-platforms;visibility=public-images;search=hadoop), you'll see that there are quite a few. Thus, one way around this issue is to work in the US-East-1 region (this is simplest) or, alternatively, set `EC2_URL` in your login script via `export EC2_URL=https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` but now you need make sure you put your keys in this region from the AWS console.

If you did indeed change `HADOOP_VERSION` to `1.0.4`, I'll note that

```
ec2-describe-images -a | grep hadoop-images 
                       | grep "1.0.4"'
                       | grep x86
                       | grep available
```

doesn't return any images in the US-East-1 region. Note that the version (`HADOOP_VERSION`) of the Hadoop distribution that you are running the `hadoop-ec2` command from does not need to be the same as the version of Hadoop that the images will be running.

Lastly, as a blunt fix, you could find the AMI that you want to use, and force set `AMI_IMAGE` to the image name in the `launch-hadoop-master` and `launch-hadoop-cluster` scripts.